# Unable to launch Ubuntu18.04 on VirtualBox [VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED]

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu18.04 was working fine for me on VirtualBox v6.x until I got windows updates (insider preview). Now any of my old as well any new VM is crashing with following error

> Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87)
>   (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).
>
> Result Code:  E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component:  ConsoleWrap Interface: 
>   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I don't want to uninstall windows updates unless there is no solution to this problem.

pls let me know if any quick fix available for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching for couple of hours and trying various things..finally below method worked for me on Windows 10

In order to allow VirtualBox to run properly you need to enable/disable following windows feature by going into programs and feature (`Win + R >> appwiz.cpl`)

1. Disable Hyper-V (if it is available on your machine)
2. Enable "Virtual Machine platform"
3. Enable "Windows Hypervisor platform"
4. Disable "Windows Sandbox" (if available on your machine)
5. Open Poweshell command prompt as admin and then run followng command

   `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
6. Restart machine

and the error should go away...

Answer (score 2):

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) feature was enabled. This solved it for me:
1) go to **Windows features** and **disable WSL**
2) restart
3*) if still doesn't work, enter the following command (turn off HyperV as mentioned in the previous answer)

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

then
4*) restart
  *In my case, step 1) and 2) were enough

Answer (score 0):

If nothing from suggested answer works for you try to go to:
Windows Features -> uncheck Virtual Machine Platform. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me so I followed the thread here which says: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=104175&p=507408

> I get the same problem with 6.1.28
>
> I have tired the following Virtualbox versions: OKAY -
> VirtualBox-6.1.26-145957-Win.exe OKAY -
> VirtualBox-6.1.27-147422-Win.exe (test build) OKAY -
> VirtualBox-6.1.97-147373-Win.exe (yes 6.1.97 test build) BAD -
> VirtualBox-6.1.28-147628-Win.exe
>
> So it looks like a change between SVN 147422 and 147628 has caused the
> NEMR0InitVMPart2 failure to occur.
>
> I have changed between the different versions listed above without any
> reboots or Windows changes, so the only changes are with the different
> VirtualBox installs.

I upgraded my Oracle Virtual Box from 6.1.28 to 6.1.30 and that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Turn Windows features on or off.

- Enable Hyper-V

Comment: This adds nothing to current answers, why post this at all?