# How do I this fix VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED in Virtual-Box?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

After installing windows 98 in virtualbox, I clicked 'start' button. Then it showed me an error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine windows 98.

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

**VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).**

You need virtualization Technology enabled in the Bios

- Reboot your machine
- Press F10 to enter BIOS.
- Security-> System Security
- Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology
- Save and start the machine.

**Failed to open a session for the virtual machine windows 98.**

There are different approaches to solve this, try whichever works for you

### 1

> - open windows features win+R  --> then optionalfeatures
> - Disable Hyper-V (if it is available on your machine)
> - Enable "Virtual Machine platform"
> - Enable "Windows Hypervisor platform"
> - Disable "Windows Sandbox" (if available on your machine)
> - Restart the machine

### 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) feature was enabled.

> - Disabling it solved it for me.
> - Restart the machine.

### 3

If it still doesn't work:

> - Open Powershell command prompt as admin and then run the following command:

> ```
> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
> ```
>
> - Restart the machine

View the full answer:
[Unable to launch Ubuntu18.04 on VirtualBox [VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012338/unable-to-launch-ubuntu18-04-on-virtualbox-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)